# Construction URI in Android

Tags: android, uri

How can I construct a URI to table MediaStore.Files.FileColumns ?
I try like this:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns);
```

But in Eclipse "MediaStore.Files.FileColumns" is underlined. I guess, I do this wrong. How to correctly construct a URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileColumns is interface. You cannot reference interface. If you need explicit column, use

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.<COLUMN>);
```

for example:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was so close:)

Answer (score 0):

MediaStore.Files.FileColumns is an Interface, the method Uri.parse() receives a string.